# What is the derivative of an operator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, differentiation

Let's say I have an operator U(t) which acts on some function f(t).

Does $\frac{dU}{dt} = V(t)$ where $ V(t)[f(t)] = \frac{d}{dt} (U(t)[f(t)])$?

Or is it $\frac{dU}{dt} = W(t)$ where $W(t)[f] = \frac{\partial}{\partial t}|_{f}(U(t)[f])$

Comment: It's the latter... or closer to the latter. You don't need to reference the function at all.

Comment: Related (possible dupe?) https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/604803/25301

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing as $\hat{U}$ here is actually not itself an operator ... but an operator-valued function *of a real number*. Thus, because linear operators on a Hilbert space support enough "features" (namely subtraction, scaling, and topology), you can define its derivative in the same way you would any other function of a real number:

$$\frac{d\hat{U}}{dt}(t) := \lim_{\Delta t \rightarrow 0} \frac{\hat{U}(t + \Delta t) - \hat{U}(t)}{\Delta t}.$$

In particular, its action upon a function $f$ is given by your second equation.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the difference between an operator-value function and an operator?


Furthermore, how would one represent $\frac{d}{dt} (\hat{U} f)$? $\frac{d\hat{U}}{dt}f + \hat{U}\frac{df}{dt}$ ?

Comment: @Tanmay Neema: It's the same as the difference between a number-valued function and a number. The function associates an operator with each number, while the number-valued function associates another number with each number.